# h5py, access data in Datasets in SVHN

Tags: python, h5py

I want to read [the Street View House Numbers (SVHN) Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) by using h5py

```
In [117]: def printname(name):
     ...:     print(name)
     ...:

In [118]: data['/digitStruct'].visit(printname)
bbox
name
```

There are two group in the data, `bbox` and `name`, `name` is the group name corresponding to the file name data, and `bbox` is the group name corresponding to the width, height, top, left and label data.

How can I visit all the data in `name` and `bbox` group?

I have tried with the following code from the [Docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html), but it just return HDF5 object reference.

```
In [119]: for i in data['/digitStruct/name']:
     ...:     print(i[0])
     ...:
     ...:
<HDF5 object reference>
<HDF5 object reference>
<HDF5 object reference>
<HDF5 object reference>
<HDF5 object reference>
<HDF5 object reference>
```

Python version: 3.5 and OS: Windows 10.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll answer my question here, after read the docs of `h5py`, here is my code

```
def get_box_data(index, hdf5_data):
    """
    get `left, top, width, height` of each picture
    :param index:
    :param hdf5_data:
    :return:
    """
    meta_data = dict()
    meta_data['height'] = []
    meta_data['label'] = []
    meta_data['left'] = []
    meta_data['top'] = []
    meta_data['width'] = []

    def print_attrs(name, obj):
        vals = []
        if obj.shape[0] == 1:
            vals.append(obj[0][0])
        else:
            for k in range(obj.shape[0]):
                vals.append(int(hdf5_data[obj[k][0]][0][0]))
        meta_data[name] = vals

    box = hdf5_data['/digitStruct/bbox'][index]
    hdf5_data[box[0]].visititems(print_attrs)
    return meta_data

def get_name(index, hdf5_data):
    name = hdf5_data['/digitStruct/name']
    return ''.join([chr(v[0]) for v in hdf5_data[name[index][0]].value])
```

Here the `hdf5_data` is `train_data = h5py.File('./train/digitStruct.mat')`, it works fine!

### Update

Here is some sample code to use the above two functions

```
mat_data = h5py.File(os.path.join(folder, 'digitStruct.mat'))
size = mat_data['/digitStruct/name'].size

for _i in tqdm.tqdm(range(size)):
    pic = get_name(_i, mat_data)
    box = get_box_data(_i, mat_data)
```

The above function shows how to get the name and the bbox data of each entry of the data!

Comment: In this should we input 0 for index while calling the function? And also could you explain how this function works?

Comment: Thank you.After using your code,I figured this out myself also.Could you throw some light on the print_attrs function?

Comment: @DhruvMarwha, `print_attrs` is a function to get data in each bbox. And you can read the docs of [visititems of h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html?highlight=visititems) and also to see the details of `box = hdf5_data['/digitStruct/bbox'][index]` and `hdf5_data[box[0]]` to know the details of the code. Note that `h5py` is not a high performance library, so you can picklized the data first and use it.

Comment: I'm assuming you have used this dataset @Alexander Yau.In this as you know there are lenghts of lines for boundary boxes.I was thinking of drawing those boxes around the characters.I tried but since i do not the starting points,i cannot draw the boundary boxes around the digits.Any thoughts?

Comment: @DhruvMarwha, `SVHN` data contains the bbox data, so you can try the above function to get the box data.

Answer (score 0):

I make a similar function to get the metadata of the bounding boxes based on your answer, but without using `visititems()` since I'm still not familiar with it.  Instead, it makes use of the dictionary properties of the `h5py.File`.

```
f = h5py.File(digi_file, 'r')
bboxs = f['digitStruct/bbox']

def get_img_boxes(f, idx=0):
    """
    get the 'height', 'left', 'top', 'width', 'label' of bounding boxes of an image
    :param f: h5py.File
    :param idx: index of the image
    :return: dictionary
    """
    meta = { key : [] for key in ['height', 'left', 'top', 'width', 'label']}

    box = f[bboxs[idx][0]]
    for key in box.keys():
        if box[key].shape[0] == 1:
            meta[key].append(int(box[key][0][0]))
        else:
            for i in range(box[key].shape[0]):
                meta[key].append(int(f[box[key][i][0]][()].item()))

    return meta
```

To get the bounding boxes information of a specific image, just call the function with an index:

```
boxes = get_img_boxes(f, 2)
```