# Managing HDF5 Object Reference

Tags: python, hdf5

I am trying to load a mat file for the  Street View House Numbers (SVHN) Dataset http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/ in Python with the following code

```
import h5py
labels_file = './sv/train/digitStruct.mat'
f = h5py.File(labels_file)
struct= f.values()
names = struct[1].values()
print(names[1][1].value)
```

I get `[<HDF5 object reference>]` but I need to know the actual string

Comment: are you entirely sure you can read it using h5py?  Which version of Matlab was used? See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python)

Comment: it seems the file is parsed if I try print(names[1]) I get <HDF5 dataset "name": shape (33402, 1), type "|O">

Comment: Have you checked the data layout? Use `h5dump ./sv/train/digitStruct.mat` in the terminal to see a bit what's going on.

Comment: sorry the question was not well rendered due to the [ characters. I have fixed it

Comment: do you expect to find the name of the files?

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of the data layout you could execute

```
h5dump ./sv/train/digitStruct.mat
```

but there are also other methods like `visit` or `visititems`.

A good reference that can help you and that seems to have already addressed a very similar problem (if not the same) recently is the following SO post:
[h5py, access data in Datasets in SVHN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176258/h5py-access-data-in-datasets-in-svhn)
For example the snippet:

```
import h5py
import numpy

def get_name(index, hdf5_data):
    name = hdf5_data['/digitStruct/name']
    print ''.join([chr(v[0]) for v in hdf5_data[name[index][0]].value])

labels_file = 'train/digitStruct.mat'
f = h5py.File(labels_file)
for j in range(33402):
    get_name(j, f)
```

will print the name of the files. I get for example:

> 7459.png
>   7460.png
>   7461.png
>   7462.png
>   7463.png
>   7464.png
>   7465.png

You can generalize from here.

Comment: I am sorry the question was not well rendered due to the [ characters. I have fixed it. Please check it out, thanks a lot.

Comment: If I tried this, it is really really slow (about 3 minutes to get 50 names on a good i7), do you have an idea ?