# Accessing data in SVHN dataset in python

Tags: python, h5py, mat

I tried to extract data from tar.gz file which contains digitStruct.mat file.
I used the following code snippet:

```
train_dataset = h5py.File('./train/digitStruct.mat')
```

I want to access the bbox and name details from this object itself. 
for eg:

```
train_dataset[0]
```

Should output something like:

```
{'boxes': [{'height': 219.0,
'label': 1.0,
'left': 246.0,
'top': 77.0,
'width': 81.0},
{'height': 219.0, 'label': 9.0, 'left': 323.0, 'top': 81.0, 'width': 96.0}],
 'filename': '1.png'}
```

I searched for it and found the some help on this link:

[h5py, access data in Datasets in SVHN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176258/h5py-access-data-in-datasets-in-svhn)

But the above link involves creating seperate functions get_box_data(index, hdf5_data) and get_name(index, hdf5_data) to retrieve value for the corresponding index.
However, I want access it directly from the variable name train_dataset[index].

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not that simple. This is MATLAB data saved using the MATLAB v7.3 file option. That format/schema uses **object pointers** and is a nightmare to work with if you don't understand them. I wrote some code to read and convert this data to a "normal HDF5 format". I thought I posted on SO, but can't find it. I'll dig around my archives. In the meantime, look at my answer in this post that explains object pointers as used in SVHN dataset. [accessing the hdf5 group in SVHN dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643382/10462884)

Comment: Is 'left'=x1 and 'top'=y1 coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found what I mentioned in the comments above.  It converts a SVHN HDF5 file in .mat v7.3 format into something simpler to work with. The file name is entered as `dsFileName=`. (I only had 6 test files to convert, so didn't add an input mechanism.) It takes a file named: `yourfilename.mat` and converts to `yourfilename.h5`. The second file is much easier to work with (and smaller and faster!). The new .h5 file has a dataset named `digitStruct` with the following records on each line:

- **name**: String (file name, eg `1.png`)
- **label**: String with digit value (0-9)
- **left**: image bounding box left
- **top**: image bounding box top
- **width**: image bounding box width
- **height**: image bounding box height

Note: This calls code shared on github. URL and Attribution included in the source code below.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import os
import digitStruct
## Note digitStruct.py source found at:
## https://github.com/prijip/Py-Gsvhn-DigitStruct-Reader/blob/master/digitStruct.py

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    dsFileName = 'Stanford/extra/digitStruct.mat'
    print ('Working on',os.path.split(dsFileName))

    print ('Create .h5 called',os.path.splitext(dsFileName)[0]+'.h5')
    h5f = h5py.File(os.path.splitext(dsFileName)[0]+'.h5', 'w')
    print ('Created',os.path.split(h5f.filename))

# Count number of images in digitStruct.mat file [/name] dataset
    mat_f = h5py.File(dsFileName)
    num_img = mat_f['/digitStruct/name'].size
    mat_f.close()

    ds_dtype = np.dtype ( [('name','S16'), ('label','S10'), ('left','f8'),
                            ('top','f8'), ('width','f8'), ('height','f8')] )
    ds_recarray = np.recarray ( (10,) , dtype=ds_dtype )
    ds_table = h5f.create_dataset('digitStruct', (2*num_img,), dtype=ds_dtype, maxshape=(None,) )

    idx_dtype = np.dtype ( [('name','S16'), ('first','i4'), ('length','i4')] )
##    idx_recarray = np.recarray ( (1,) , dtype=idx_dtype )
    idx_table = h5f.create_dataset('idx_digitStruct', (num_img,), dtype=idx_dtype, maxshape=(None,) )

    imgCounter = 0
    lblCounter = 0

    for dsObj in digitStruct.yieldNextDigitStruct(dsFileName):
        if (imgCounter % 1000 == 0) :
               print(dsObj.name)

        if (idx_table.shape[0] < imgCounter ) : # resize idx_table as needed
            idx_table.resize(idx_table.shape[0]+1000, axis=0)

        idx_table[imgCounter,'name'] = dsObj.name
        idx_table[imgCounter,'first'] = lblCounter
        idx_table[imgCounter,'length'] = len(dsObj.bboxList)

        raCounter = 0

        for bbox in dsObj.bboxList:

            ds_recarray[raCounter]['name'] = dsObj.name
            ds_recarray[raCounter]['label'] = bbox.label
            ds_recarray[raCounter]['left'] = bbox.left
            ds_recarray[raCounter]['top'] = bbox.top
            ds_recarray[raCounter]['width'] = bbox.width
            ds_recarray[raCounter]['height'] = bbox.height
            raCounter += 1
            lblCounter += 1

        if (ds_table.shape[0] < lblCounter ) :   # resize ds_table as needed
            ds_table.resize(ds_table.shape[0]+1000, axis=0)
        ds_table[lblCounter-raCounter:lblCounter] = ds_recarray[0:raCounter]

        imgCounter += 1

##        if imgCounter >= 2000:
##            break

    print ('Total images processed:', imgCounter )
    print ('Total labels processed:', lblCounter )

    ds_table.resize(lblCounter, axis=0)
    idx_table.resize(imgCounter, axis=0)

    h5f.close()
```